# Create GitLab release with markdown description using GitLab Releases API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am following the documentation for the GitLab Releases API here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#create-a-release

The documentation notes that the description supports markdown. However when I pass markdown in the description the formatting is not correct.

The JSON request body is as follows:

```
{
    "tag_name": "1.0.0-RC-2",
    "description": "# 1.0.0-RC-2
### Bug Fixes
* Update README.md"
}
```

However when the release is created, the description is all on one line, when it really should be on 3 separate lines in this example. Because of this the description formatting is incorrect. How can the description be passed in JSON format with the correct markdown format?

Answer (score 3):

That json isn't valid. You can copy your whole json body and paste it into something like jsonlint.com to validate if your json is syntactically correct (your example isn't).

I'm guessing perhaps that GitLab is taking the multi-line description and automatically removing the newlines in the string? I'm not sure to be honest, I would have expected an error since it's considered invalid.

To fix it, all you have to do is replace the newlines with `\n`. GitLab should recognize these as well so that your end result will look the way you want it to.

Here's the json body of one I just created for one of my projects:

```json
{
    "name": "A Test Release",
    "tag_name": "v0.0.0",
    "ref": "main",
    "description": "# 1.0.0-RC-2\n### Bug Fixes\n* Update README.md"
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]